# Which CNC gantry support shape is more ridgid?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics, cnc

I'm in the process of designing a small CNC. There are two styles of side plates for supporting the gantry. The first one has an angled corner cut on the front, while the other has a backslash shape. I'm planning them out of 1/2 thick steel plate.

I'm having difficulty figuring out the advantages of one design over the other in terms of rigidity. Intuitively, the second one seems less rigid because it has less material, but there must be a good reason for this design.

[image: Front angled]
[image: Forward Backslash Plate]

Comment: I think you're splitting hairs. That cantilever overhand is going to overshadow the difference between the two.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify?  Do you mean the weight of the spindle assembly?

Comment: Well, not only the weight but the cutting forces acting on it since it is overhanging off one side like a cantilever rather than centered. It might not matter for your intended usage, but if it doesn't matter then neither does the difference in this question you have asked.